# Trouble placing leveraged order using ccxt library with ByBit

Tags: ccxt, bybit, python-bybit

I'm trying to place a market order using 75x leverage using futures derivates (ETH/USDT) on bybit with ccxt but it keeps producing the same error:

`An error occurred while placing the order: bybit {"retCode":140007,"retMsg":"remark:order[49649307 cc209816-b438-49ce-900f-6f21b709a007] fix price failed for CannotAffordOrderCost.","result":{},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1686541985452}`

I have 27 USDT in my wallet, and currently my code fetches my balance and the symbol, and in this example goes for a short. First i tried to use my balance as the amount (27) then i tried using how much eth id like to short with the amonunt of leverage im using. So with 75x leverage of 27, i tried to retrieve the max amount of eth i could short which is 1.1 or something. I cant do any leverage lower than 75x because then it becomes less than 1 eth, and the code would then print the error: An error occurred while placing the order: bybit amount of ETH/USD:ETH must be greater than minimum amount precision of 1

Heres my code:

````
symbol ="ETHUSD"
leverage = 75
def set_leverage():
    try:
        exchange.set_leverage(leverage, symbol)
        print(f"Leverage set to {leverage}x for {symbol}.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while setting the leverage: {e}")

set_leverage()

def place_order(symbol, side):
    balance = get_balance()
    current_price = get_current_price(symbol)
    amount = ((balance / current_price) * leverage) * 0.95
    side = 'Buy' if side == 'long' else 'Sell'
    print(amount)
    try:
        exchange.create_market_order(symbol, side, amount)
        print(f"Market {side} order of {balance} {symbol} placed.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while placing the order: {e}")```
````